# Longest word with adjacent letters on a keyboard (without using any letters twice)

Tags: word

I know this question is very similar to GOTO 0's [Longest word with adjacent letters on a keyboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11408), but all the answers to GOTO 0's question had many repeating letters. I need to find a word in [this list](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt) that all the letters within are adjacent to the next on a QWERTY keyboard layout, that also only uses each letter once.

GOTO 0's keyboard for reference

```
 ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 | Q | W | E | R | T | Y | U | I | O | P |
 └─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┘
   | A | S | D | F | G | H | J | K | L |
   └─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴───┘
     | Z | X | C | V | B | N | M |
     └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: Can you define adjacent in this context? For instance are diagonals allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I could find were two rather short words:

> sawed
>  trews

Comment: What did you use to find those words? Would I be able to use it to sort through other lists on my own?

Comment: @VerySpecificWordSearcher https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/0e905a9d3567aabc75fe52f4e896d79a

Answer (score 3):

> trews - five letters .................